# In Tableau, how to pass values to action filters that are not in pie chart?

Tags: tableau-api

I am using Tableau desktop 8.1.
I have created a pie chart showing Shift timings and number of employees in each shift timings under different departments.

The pie chart is as follows :
Shift Timing  as the "Color mark"
Count distinct employee as the "Angle mark"

I have created an action filter whereby clicking on a shift timing in the Pie chart will display another sheet which shows various details of the employee under that particular shift time.
I have used Action Filter where the field i have passed to the target filter is "Shift Time".But i am not able to add the Department Field as a target filter to the Actions Filter as tableau desktop displays an error "Missing fields on Pie chart".
I need to pass the Department also to the Action filter ( but it is not present in the pie chart) as the user might select Multiple departments from the given list of Departments and the report should show the

My requirement is that if the user selects Shift time (for e.g 9am-5pm) and four departments then upon clicking the 9am-5pm shift in the pie chart should display the details of employees under those departments.I am not able to achieve this because i am not able to pass the Department as target filter into the Action filter.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: No matter what your boss tells you, I strongly recommend looking for alternative to pie charts to offer. Humans are very bad at interpreting pie charts - there are many more effective choices. For some examples, take a look at http://www.businessinsider.com/the-27-worst-charts-of-all-time-2013-6?op=1

Comment: Ditto what @AlexBlakemore said.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit difficult to understand without seeing your actual workbook.

If I understand correctly, you want do display a pie chart, and when I click on a segment of the pie chart, you want to display a list of employees under that segment (shift time), but you also want to filter the department.

What I would do is to create a dashboard with 2 sheets, 1 with your pie chart, and one with the employee names/ids (simply drag employee name/id field to the rows and that's all). On the second sheet I would include a filter using department field.

Back on dashboard I would go to the pie chart sheet, click on the gray triangle on the top right, and select "Use as Filter". Then I would go to the other sheet, click the same triangle, go on Quick Filters and select the department filter. And voilà, the user is able to filter departments on the right of your dashboard, and click on the pie segments to select a shift.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I have another way to resolve this issue.

Dashboard->Action->add action - >
[image]